# Blend file size is huge

Tags: texturing, blend-files, data-blocks

After adding image as planes and use as a particle, size of File and used by ram is increased from 35MB to 568MB.

Ram used 350MB to 10GB

Even if i add ivy file size is 35MB.

Only 3 textures are used (5MB).

[image: blend file size]

Comment: What did you expect when using particles?

Comment: Why does your computer display only two spaces in between the commas?

Comment: Particle which are stable bot moving any direction or location i just used for leaf and i also convert into the mesh and also leaves are not much than ivy

Comment: About comma i don't know

Comment: Don't convert particles to mesh and the size won't soar up.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer needs to save every single particle position, rotation, scale, physics, etc. in order to properly display them. For a single particle, this isn't much- but it adds up, especially with thousands of them.

Comment: I convert the particle to mesh and there is no particle system at the moment but still so much memory

Comment: I need to do anything in data blocks?  I also purge all but its getting No orphan...  Any solution

Comment: applying the particle system won't do any good. Try going into the particle settings and under "viewport display", lower the percentage. In the viewport your computer will render less particles, thus taking less memory to do so, but everything will show up in your final render.